# CakePHP Saving hasMany association

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, associations, cakephp-3.x

i've a product that needs to save an image path to another table. `product hasMany images`.

This is my `add()`

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    // https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations
    $save = $this->Products->newEntity(
        $this->request->getData(),
        ['associated'=>$associated]
    );

    $this->log('JUST AFTER PATCH'.$save);
    $save->last_modified = Time::now();
    $save->created = Time::now();

    //sort out assoc.
    $path = $this->saveImageGetPath($this->request->data['images']);

    $save['images'][] = [
        'path' => $path,
        'alt_description' => $product->name . Time::now() . 'img',
        'position' => $this->request->data['position']
    ];

    $save->isDirty(true);
    $this->log('JUST BEFORE SAVE'.$save);
    if ($this->Products->save($save, [
        'associated'=> ['Shoes', 'Images', 'Products_has_categories']
    ])) {
```

This is the array output to the log

```
{
    "name":"xlc",
    "brands_id":1,
    "description":"csvfd",
    "type":"s",
    "position":"0",
    "shoe":{
        "heels_id":1,
        "closures_id":1,
        "materials_upper_id":1,
        "materials_lining_id":1,
        "materials_sole_id":1
    },
    "products_has_categories":{
        "categories_id":"1"
    },
    "images":[
        {
            "path":"\/webroot\/img\/products\/img1503289958.jpg",
            "alt_description":"8\/21\/17, 4:32 AMimg",
            "position":"0"
        }
    ],
    "last_modified":"2017-08-21T04:32:38+00:00",
    "created":"2017-08-21T04:32:38+00:00"
}
```

This is the table `Image` assoc.

```
$this->hasMany('Images', [
    'foreignKey' => 'products_id',
    'dependent' => true,
]);
```

The images upload fine and you can get the path. It's just not triggering a SQL statement for this and i'm baffled as to why
Do note, that a `hasOne` assoc. does work, so I can save assoc. but not with this `hasMany`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the image as an array to the data, that won't work, the ORM will only save entity objects, ie you have to create an instance of `\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface` instead (that's what the entity creation/patching process will do automatically for the passed data).

```
$save['images'][] = $this->Products->Images->newEntity([
    'path' => $path,
    'alt_description' => $product->name . Time::now() . 'img',
    'position' => $this->request->data['position']
]);
```

Also you need to make sure that the `images` property is being marked as dirty, as otherwise the ORM will ignore it (that's also being done automatically in the entity creation/patching process). Your `isDirty(true)` call won't do anything, as `isDirty()` isn't a setter, but a getter.

```
$save->setDirty('images', true); // use dirty('images', true) in CakePHP < 3.4
```

Also instead of logging JSON representations, you better use `debug()`, or at least `var_export()` instead, in order to retain the debugging information that the entity provides.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Saving With Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-with-associations)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Saving HasMany Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasmany-associations)**

Comment: You are a god, thank you so much. That is the perfect answer